# Ruby Undefined Method (in model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am getting a NoMethodError when trying to call my "not_coworker_friend" or "coworker_friend" method.  I am working in Ruby MVC.  This is my current code, **As written it does not produce any errors**:

```
class EmergencyTrip < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

has_attached_file :receipt
validates_attachment_presence :receipt

validates_presence_of :trip_cost, :if => :not_coworker_friend
validates_presence_of  :phone_of_person, :if => :coworker_friend

def not_coworker_friend
  (self.ride_home_service == "co-worker/friend") ? false : true
end

def coworker_friend
  (self.ride_home_service == "co-worker/friend") ? true : false
end

end
```

My objective is to only validate the receipt if "not_coworker_friend" == true.

Lines 5 & 6 should be:

```
...
has_attached_file :receipt, :if => :not_coworker_friend
validates_attachment_presence :receipt, :if => :not_coworker_friend
...
```

Adding the ":if => not_coworker_friend" to those lines generates a NoMethodError (undefined method `call' for :not_coworker_friend:Symbol):, even though there is no error thrown for lines 8 & 9.  Why does this only selectively throw an error?  And how can I correct this?

Comment: define method before using it. Just in case.

Comment: I changed so the method was defined before use but this did not work.  There is no error for when it is called on lines 8 & 9 regardless, so it has to be defined.

Comment: Should work like this. Maybe reload console? but please read up on boolean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type

Comment: @Fallenhero I have reloaded my console and restarted my whole application  many times and rebuilt and clean.  Of course it should work like this... but it does not so I am asking why

Comment: You could try it for now with a `Proc.new ...`

Comment: Which rails are you using? I copied your code and it works. So I am guessing the problem lies somewhere else completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
class EmergencyTrip < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :receipt, :if => Proc.new{|f| f.ride_home_service != "co-worker/friend"}
    validates_attachment_presence :receipt, :if => Proc.new{|f| f.ride_home_service != "co-worker/friend"}
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  you helped me a lot.